# Unable to inject array list as dependency

Tags: java, spring

I am creating a bean with annotations.

```
@Component
public class MyClass
{

    @Autowired
    private ArrayList<String> myFriends= new ArrayList<String>();

   //Getters and setters  

}
```

I am getting the following exception

**Could not autowire field: private java.util.ArrayList com.mypackage.MyClass.myFriends; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.util.ArrayList] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}**

I also tried with this

```
@Resource
    private ArrayList<String> myFriends= new ArrayList<String>();
```

I am getting the following exception

**No matching bean of type [java.util.ArrayList] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, mappedName=, description=, name=, type=class java.lang.Object, authenticationType=CONTAINER)}**

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Do you understand what you're trying to do, right?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. I am trying to create a bean with a property as List

Comment: What do you expect to be injected?

Comment: No, you're trying to create a bean and inject an `ArrayList` from nowhere. You should inject object instances as interface implementors, not `List` or `Map` objects. Also, the exception messages are pretty clear: *No matching bean of type [java.util.ArrayList] found for dependency* and *expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. When I remove Autowired annotation, I am getting exception as method not found in the class.

Comment: Probably you have other problems in your code (not posted here so impossible to analyse).

Comment: Yeah I will try to analyze and post. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the XML file you would need to define a list.

In the XML file include the util namespace and add the following bean definition.

```xml
<util:list id="myFriends">
 <value>string1</value>
 <value>string2</value>
 <value>string3</value>
</util:list>
```

You need to change the type of the variable to `List<String>` instead of `ArrayList<String>`. That will make it easier to inject and is also a better coding practice to follow.  You need to add a Qualifier annotation to specify the id of the bean that needs to be injected, qualifier might not be required if you have only one such list.

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myFriends")
    private List<String> myFriends= new ArrayList<String>();
    //Getters and setters
}
```

Link to spring reference documentation for util:list
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-list

Comment: While you have a point here, this is indeed not a real world usage of  `@Autowired`. Note that even while injecting the list, you're assigning a new value to it =\.

Comment: the util:list was created for this purpose.  There might be cases where I would need to inject a list of vlaues (list of server ips for example).  Also it is a good practice to always initialize any list reference to an empty list. That way if the object is used in a  non spring context (unit test for e.g.,) it will work correctly instead of throwing a null pointer exception (NullObject pattern).

Comment: If you're already using Spring, you can (and I bet you will) use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` to get all the power from Spring. IMO, I would have the list of values in a different properties file, not in the spring.xml for distribution purposes. Taking your example, I would have a list of server ips for development stage and a totally different one for qa and production stages, so instead of having 3 spring.xml configuration files I would prefer to have 3 different configuration environments with the proper config files and their respective values :).

Comment: For unit test it is preferred not to use spring - mock / stub dependencies.  SpringJUnit4ClassRunner is for integration tests.  Also with 3.2 profiles you can have bean with same id defined in multiple profiles (test, qa, prod) and then choose one while running it.  I am not suggesting that this should be used everywhere, but it is a valid option.