# annotation based injection; initialize an empty map

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring > Annotation based injection

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> myMap;

    public MyClass() {
        myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public void foo() {
        myMap.put("a", "b");
    }
}
```

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

          <context:component-scan base-package="com.basePackage" />
          <context:annotation-config/>

    </beans>
```

main() class

```
public class MyMain() {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    // [EDITED. ADDED NOW - BEGIN]
    ApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext(
        "myApplicationContext.xml");
    // [EDITED. ADDED NOW - END]

        MyClass myObj = (MyClass) context.getBean(MyClass.class);
        myObj.foo();
    }
}
```

myObj.foo() raises a NPE.
I was expecting that: When I get bean, the constructor of map is called and map gets instantiated and code runs smoothly.

Neither this worked:
private ConcurrentHashMap myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();

How do I get this code working. 
NOTE:

- I do not want to add part configuration in xml and part in java. That too I am trying to instantiate with an empty map.
- I want to get this working in annotation way itself and get map instantiated empty before I first use it.

Comment: Please post your XML and the `ApplicationContext` initialization.

Comment: a related question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663660/initialize-empty-arraylists-in-spring-configuration).   Approaches in this did not work really for me though in my case

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem. There must be something you  aren't showing us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not be showing us all the details. The exception isn't hapenning because your `ConcurrentHashMap` is `null`. It is happening because your are passing a `null` object on your `put()` method call. The `ConcurrentHashMap` class does not support `null` keys. The javadoc states

> Like Hashtable but unlike HashMap, this class does not allow null to
>   be used as a key or value.

Comment: Yes U r right. I realized this when I was trying again to run the program. Thanks my problem is solved

Comment: @smc Glad I could help. Consider upvoting and accepting any answers that were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There can be no NPE here unless your context is null. If there is no MyClass.class in the context NoSuchBeanDefinitionException would be thrown. If you managed to get the bean the context then it is initialized and myMap is an empty map. Look for there problem somehwere else

Comment: My test runs give me an NPE.   Here is a snapshot:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException  
 at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:333)  
 at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1125)  
 at com.basePackage.MyClass.foo(MyClass.java:21)  
 at com.basePackage.MyMain.main(MyMain.java:28)

Answer (score 0):

first:you need setter & getter in MyClass for the field myMap.
second: you don't use new operation in the MyClass for myMap because

```
MyClass myObj = (MyClass) context.getBean(MyClass.class);
```

does injection and of course allocate memory for it.

Comment: You do not need getter and setter if you aren't setting a `<bean>` `<property>`.